# concept of converting from UTF8 to UTF16 LE the math operation in c programming

Tags: c, embedded

I would like to know the concept of conversion from UTF8 to UTF16 LE

for e.g 
input sequence     E3 81 82
output sequence is   42 30

what is the actual arithmetic operation in this conversion.(I do not want to call in-built libraries)

Comment: You’ll do it in two steps.  (1) Convert UTF8 to UTF32; (2) convert UTF32 to UTF16-LE.  Neither is particularly simple, though they’re far from impossible.  Trying to combine them would lead to excruciating code.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Unicode is a way to represent many as possible symbols in one continuous code space, the code of each symbol is usually called a "*code point*".
*UTF-8* and *UTF-16* are just ways to encode and represent those code point in one or more octets (UTF-8) or 16-bit words (UTF-16), the latest can be represented as pair of octets in either *little-endian* ("least significant first" or "Intel byte order") or *big-endian* ("most significant first", or "Motorola byte order") sequence, which gives us two variants: UTF-16LE and UTF-16BE.

First you need to do, is to extract the code point from the UTF-8 sequence. 
UTF-8 is encoded as follows:

**0x00...0x7F** encode symbol "as-is", it corresponds to standard ASCII symbols

but, if most significant bit is set (i.e. **0x80...0xFF**), then it means that this is a sequence of several bytes, which all together encode the code point

bytes from range **0xC0...0xFF** are on the first position of that sequence, in binary representation they will be:

- 0b**110xxxxx** - 1 more byte follows and xxxxx are 5 most significant bits of the code point
- 0b**1110xxxx** - 2 more bytes follow and xxxx are 4 most significant bits of the code point
- 0b**11110xxx** - 3 more bytes...
- 0b**111110xx** - 4 more bytes...

There are no code points defined in Unicode standard, which require more than 5 UTF-8 bytes for now.

following bytes are from range **0x80...0xBF** (i.e. 0b**10xxxxxx**) and encode next six bits (from most to least significant) from the code point value.

So, looking at your example: E3 81 82

- 0xE3 == 0b**1110***0011* means there will be more 2 bytes in this code point and *0011* - are most significant bits of it
- 0x81 == 0b**10***000001* means this is not the first byte in the code point sequence and it encodes next 6 bits: *000001*
- 0x82 == 0b**10***000010* means this is not the first byte in the code point sequence and it encodes next 6 bits: *000010*

i.e. result will be *0011 000001 000010* == **0x3042**

**UTF-16** works the same way. Most usual code points are just encoded "as-is" but some large values are packed in so-called "surrogate pairs", which are combination of two 16-bit words:

- values from range **0xD800...0xDBFF** represents the first of them, its 10 lower bits are encoding 10 most significant bits of the resulting code point.
- values from range **0xDC00...0xDFFF** represents the second, its lower bits are encoding 10 least significant bits of the resulting code point.

Surrogate pairs are required for values more than 0xFFFF (obvious) and for values 0xD800...0xDFFF - but this range is reserved in Unicode standard for surrogate pairs and there must no be such symbols.

So, in our example **0x3042** does not hit that range and therefore requires only one 16-bit word.

Since in your example UTF-16LE (little-endian) variant is given, that means, in the byte sequence first will be a least significant half of that word. I.e.

**0x42 0x30**

Comment: Thank you for the explanation could you please explain me a lil more about surrogate pairs if the input seq is F0 85 B6 BD what would the out put sequence be                                                                                                              F0:0b11110000    85:0b10000101      B6:0b10110110   BD:0b10111101   can this be taken in the same pattern as above  000 000101 110110 111101

Comment: It could be encoded as 3 bytes sequence in UTF-8, so it would be E5 B6 BD. Although your example gives the same result, it is not the shortest, you can consider it as an incorrect input. The code point is 0b101110110111101 = 0x5DBD, in UTF-16 it does not require an surrogate pair. So it would be just a single 16-bit word.